# Android - customizing the LatinIME issue

Tags: android, keyboard, customization, android-softkeyboard

I am creating an android application. In the app, I am planning to show my own keyboard **with the option of auto-complete and auto-correct** (**like the default keyboard with some customization**). After searching in internet I got many sample keyboard apps.

But finally I came to know that the LatinIME is the one which gives my requirements (with the option of auto-complete and auto-correct).

So that I have downloaded the LatinIME source code from the following link.
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/inputmethods/LatinIME/+/master/java

I can able to build the source code. But I couldn't install it in the emulator. Because the the default "keyboard" is already installed with the same package name as `com.android.inputmethod.latin`.

So that I have changed its package name to `"com.android.inputmethod.latin.customize"`.
But Now I can able to install the keyboard app, but I couldn't use it. I have faced the following issues.

```
1) The app installed in globally. But I want to install it only for my app. is it possible?
2) When I changed the package name I got the following issue.
04-22 18:26:59.431: E/AndroidRuntime(1206): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-22 18:26:59.431: E/AndroidRuntime(1206): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
04-22 18:26:59.431: E/AndroidRuntime(1206):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
04-22 18:26:59.431: E/AndroidRuntime(1206):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
04-22 18:26:59.431: E/AndroidRuntime(1206):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2233)
04-22 18:26:59.431: E/AndroidRuntime(1206):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:122)
04-22 18:26:59.431: E/AndroidRuntime(1206):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1200)
04-22 18:26:59.431: E/AndroidRuntime(1206):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-22 18:26:59.431: E/AndroidRuntime(1206):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-22 18:26:59.431: E/AndroidRuntime(1206):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
04-22 18:26:59.431: E/AndroidRuntime(1206):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-22 18:26:59.431: E/AndroidRuntime(1206):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-22 18:26:59.431: E/AndroidRuntime(1206):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
04-22 18:26:59.431: E/AndroidRuntime(1206):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
04-22 18:26:59.431: E/AndroidRuntime(1206):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-22 18:26:59.431: E/AndroidRuntime(1206): Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
04-22 18:26:59.431: E/AndroidRuntime(1206):     at com.android.inputmethod.latin.customize.LatinIME.<clinit>(LatinIME.java:517)
04-22 18:26:59.431: E/AndroidRuntime(1206):     ... 13 more
04-22 18:26:59.431: E/AndroidRuntime(1206): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/android/inputmethod/latin/BinaryDictionary
04-22 18:26:59.431: E/AndroidRuntime(1206):     at java.lang.Runtime.nativeLoad(Native Method)
04-22 18:26:59.431: E/AndroidRuntime(1206):     at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:368)
04-22 18:26:59.431: E/AndroidRuntime(1206):     at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:535)
04-22 18:26:59.431: E/AndroidRuntime(1206):     at com.android.inputmethod.latin.utils.JniUtils.<clinit>(JniUtils.java:28)
04-22 18:26:59.431: E/AndroidRuntime(1206):     ... 14 more
04-22 18:26:59.431: E/AndroidRuntime(1206): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.android.inputmethod.latin.BinaryDictionary
04-22 18:26:59.431: E/AndroidRuntime(1206):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
04-22 18:26:59.431: E/AndroidRuntime(1206):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
04-22 18:26:59.431: E/AndroidRuntime(1206):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
04-22 18:26:59.431: E/AndroidRuntime(1206):     ... 18 more
```

I can found the issue. In JniUtils -> System.loadLibrary("jni_latinime");
But I can't found the JNI. where should I change the "package name" in the "jni_latinime"?